# '_wctime32' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'const time_t *' to 'const __time32_t *'

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

VS 2010 Ultimate,
I occur some error C2664,

I've tried according to information found on web 
- add #include  
- change in general properties ' Use multi-byte character set'
without success.

do you have any ideas?

```
c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\time.inl(36): error C2664: '_ctime32' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'const time_t *' to 'const __time32_t *'
          Types pointed to are unrelated; conversion requires reinterpret_cast, C-style cast or function-style cast
c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\time.inl(42): error C2664: 'errno_t _ctime32_s(char *,size_t,const __time32_t *)' : cannot convert parameter 3 from 'const time_t *' to 'const __time32_t *'
          Types pointed to are unrelated; conversion requires reinterpret_cast, C-style cast or function-style cast
c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\time.inl(49): error C2664: '_gmtime32' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'const time_t *' to 'const __time32_t *'
          Types pointed to are unrelated; conversion requires reinterpret_cast,
```

it points to time.inl from MS VS

```
_CRT_INSECURE_DEPRECATE(ctime_s) static __inline char * __CRTDECL ctime(const time_t * _Time)
{
#pragma warning( push )
#pragma warning( disable : 4996 )
    return _ctime32(_Time);
#pragma warning( pop )
}
#if __STDC_WANT_SECURE_LIB__
static __inline errno_t __CRTDECL ctime_s(char *_Buffer, size_t _SizeInBytes, const time_t * _Time)
{
    return _ctime32_s(_Buffer, _SizeInBytes, _Time);
}
#endif
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you have [this problem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w4ddyt9h%28v=vs.100%29.aspx):

> versions of Visual C++ and Microsoft C/C++ before Visual C++ 2005,
>   time_t was a long int (32 bits) and hence could not be used for dates
>   past 3:14:07 January 19, 2038, UTC. **time_t is now equivalent to
>   __time64_t by default**, but defining **_USE_32BIT_TIME_T changes time_t to __time32_t and forces many time functions to call versions that
>   take the 32-bit time_t**. For more information, see Standard Types and
>   comments in the documentation for the individual time functions.

Comment: Jesse Good advice helped me to look for solution
it guided me to: [microsoft's www][1]
**in Properties -> C/C++ -> Preprocessor -> PreprocessorDefinitions**
i've added: 
**_USE_32BIT_TIME_T**
and it solve the problem.


  [1]: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/d1e92663-9804-4879-8446-da3a0bc5b86e/vc-vs2010-inline-header-errors?forum=vclanguage